# Latex code for figure using graphics,graphtex,amsmath package

Tags: graphics, captions

[image]
How to code this graph in the picture attached using this:

```
\begin{figure} [!htp]
$$\pic

\cip$$
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: "Code this for me" questions get a mixed reception on TeX.SE.  If you can post what you've tried so far, your question will be much better received.  I'd recommend starting with TikZ.  Otherwise, you may or may not get answers, and your question may or may not get closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less taken from the example just above section 43.3 of pgfmanual v3.1.4. Of course I rearranged things a bit, changed the texts, but the upshot is that many things have already been done and one can get some desired outcome by copying and modifying them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth,
    node distance=2cm,on grid]
 \begin{scope}[nodes={state}]
  \node (x_1) {$x_1$};
  \node (x_2) [left=of x_1] {$x_2$};
  \node (x_3) [right=of x_1] {$x_3$};
  \node (x_4) [above=of x_1] {$x_4$};
 \end{scope}  
 \path[->,blue,thick] foreach \X in {2,3,4} {(x_1) edge (x_\X)}
 foreach \X in {2,3} {(x_\X) edge (x_4)}
 (x_4) edge[loop right] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can put this in the figure environment of the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth,
     node distance=2cm,on grid]
  \begin{scope}[nodes={state}]
   \node (x_1) {$x_1$};
   \node (x_2) [left=of x_1] {$x_2$};
   \node (x_3) [right=of x_1] {$x_3$};
   \node (x_4) [above=of x_1] {$x_4$};
  \end{scope}  
  \path[->,blue,thick] foreach \X in {2,3,4} {(x_1) edge (x_\X)}
  foreach \X in {2,3} {(x_\X) edge (x_4)};
  \draw[->,blue,thick] (x_4) to[out=-20,in=20,looseness=12] (x_4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{A digraph $G$ of order 4.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]